# Can't install certificates for Python 3.9.7 on MacOS

Tags: python, homebrew, certifi

I installed python 3.9 via Homebrew. I created a virtual environment using that version of Python. Now I am getting SSL errors:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)>
```

I understand that Homebrew doesn't install the certificates since python 3.6. The workaround/solution that seems to be generally accepted is to run the following after the Homebrew install in my virtual environment:

```
#!/bin/sh

# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 << "EOF"

# install_certifi.py
#
# sample script to install or update a set of default Root Certificates
# for the ssl module.  Uses the certificates provided by the certifi package:
#       https://pypi.org/project/certifi/

import os
import os.path
import ssl
import stat
import subprocess
import sys

STAT_0o775 = ( stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
             | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
             | stat.S_IROTH |                stat.S_IXOTH )

def main():
    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)

    print(" -- pip install --upgrade certifi")
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,
        "-E", "-s", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "certifi"])

    import certifi

    # change working directory to the default SSL directory
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The script runs fine:

```
% python install-certificates.py
 -- pip install --upgrade certifi
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2021.10.8)
 -- removing any existing file or link
 -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle
 -- setting permissions
 -- update complete
```

However, I am still getting SSL errors. Any ideas on what the solution might be?

I have tried installing Python using the official package and running the Install certificates.command but I get an error indicating that pip isn't installed.

Comment: Try changing `pip` to `pip3`

Comment: I did but the then I get an error saying there is no module `pip3`